Camera & Negatives identification
I'm hoping someone here can help identify what type of camera my grandma is holding in this photo (sorry for blur, it's the best resolution I have) as well as the negative type I inherited. They are dated from 1940's 


it is a kodak brownie hawkeye.



Kodak Brownie Hawkeye is a Bakelite box camera that takes 12 6x6cm images on 620 film, made in the USA and France by Kodak, between 1949-1961.
Flash model was added in 1950 and called the Brownie Flash in France and the Kodak Brownie Hawkeye Flash in the USA.
The design aesthetic is a throw-back to the Art Deco era of the 1920's, with clean minimalist fluting on the sides and an attractively-designed front.

https://www.myleskatherine.com/blog/2022/12/19/kodak-brownie-hawkeye-review-with-sample-photos
https://www.35mmc.com/30/06/2021/kodak-brownie-hawkeye-a-review-of-mums-camera-by-james-hanes/
http://camera-wiki.org/wiki/Kodak_Brownie_Hawkeye
https://www.brownie-camera.com/27.shtml
https://www.jeremymuddphoto.com/blog/2023/2/21/life-in-squares-kodak-brownie-hawkeye-and-argus-seventy-five
https://alysvintagecameraalley.com/2020/10/12/kodak-brownie-hawkeye-camera-flash-model/

manual: https://www.browniecam.com/brownie_user_manuals/kodak_brownie_hawkeye.pdf
https://youtu.be/PwfhRcn5l90
https://nostalgicmedia.com/blogs/media-conversion/guide-to-negative-film-camera-formats

